# Deadlock on static-initialized jthread calling std::stacktrace_entry::description

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

The below code results in a deadlock upon exiting `main()`

```cpp
#include <stacktrace>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <semaphore>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct Singleton
{
    Singleton()
    {
        worker = std::jthread{ [this] {
            sema.acquire();
            for (auto& e : trace) {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);
                std::cout << e.description() << std::endl;
            }
        } };
    }
    std::binary_semaphore sema{ 0 };
    std::stacktrace trace;
    std::jthread worker;
};

std::stacktrace g()
{
    return std::stacktrace::current();
}

std::stacktrace f()
{
    return g();
}

Singleton& get()
{
    static Singleton sing;
    return sing;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    get().trace = f();
    get().sema.release();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(350ms);
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, calling `description()` seems to cause a deadlock in some CRT code trying to acquire a critical section.

I hypothesize that `description()` calls into some CRT code which depends on a global object in the CRT managed by a critical section. Either that object is destroyed upon exiting main before the `jthread` destructor is called, or upon exiting main the same critical section is being entered.

If this code is somehow undefined behavior, I would be grateful for someone to point out exactly what aspect of this usage is UB.

For context, this is a minimal reproduction of a problem existing in a much larger codebase, where a logging channel object containing a worker thread and lock-free queue is being managed as a singleton.

Edit: note the `sleep_for` calls are purely for illustrative purposes, they are not essential nor are they an attempt to fix a race condition. The code exhibits the same deadlocking behavior if they are removed.